# Make absolutely positioned button same width as its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have floating buttons that I want to be exactly as wide as their content. The content may be several lines long.

I have tried a lot of things, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas how to achieve this?

```js
$('button').css('width', $('button span').outerWidth() + 'px')

$.each($('button'), (i, v) => {
  $(v).css('width', $(v).find('span').outerWidth() + 'px');
  $(v).css('top', i*100 + 'px');
});
```

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

span { background: lightcoral; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>

  <button>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis iure nostrum dicta cumque. Nisi facilis corporis hic, pariatur molestiae error distinctio architecto quas itaque deserunt aliquam quo molestias dolor ex!</span>
  </button>

  <button>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</span>
  </button>

  <button>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
  </button>

  <button>
    <span>Lorem.</span>
  </button>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, provident laborum itaque ratione nisi enim delectus dolorem dicta quod, quam vitae odit officiis. Ratione pariatur eos sapiente ut expedita. Incidunt?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, provident laborum itaque ratione nisi enim delectus dolorem dicta quod, quam vitae odit officiis. Ratione pariatur eos sapiente ut expedita. Incidunt?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, provident laborum itaque ratione nisi enim delectus dolorem dicta quod, quam vitae odit officiis. Ratione pariatur eos sapiente ut expedita. Incidunt?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, provident laborum itaque ratione nisi enim delectus dolorem dicta quod, quam vitae odit officiis. Ratione pariatur eos sapiente ut expedita. Incidunt?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, provident laborum itaque ratione nisi enim delectus dolorem dicta quod, quam vitae odit officiis. Ratione pariatur eos sapiente ut expedita. Incidunt?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, provident laborum itaque ratione nisi enim delectus dolorem dicta quod, quam vitae odit officiis. Ratione pariatur eos sapiente ut expedita. Incidunt?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, provident laborum itaque ratione nisi enim delectus dolorem dicta quod, quam vitae odit officiis. Ratione pariatur eos sapiente ut expedita. Incidunt?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, provident laborum itaque ratione nisi enim delectus dolorem dicta quod, quam vitae odit officiis. Ratione pariatur eos sapiente ut expedita. Incidunt?</p>

</section>
```

Comment: Just for future reference, it's helpful in UI questions to include an example of the intended output.

Comment: Good idea, will keep it in mind, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to consider the border so add `box-sizing: content-box;` and also `1px` to the final width (I am finding why ...)

```js
$.each($('button'), (i, v) => {
  $(v).css('width', ($(v).find('span').outerWidth() + 1) + 'px');
  $(v).css('top', i * 100 + 'px');
});
```

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

span {
  background: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>

  <button>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis iure nostrum dicta cumque. Nisi facilis corporis hic, pariatur molestiae error distinctio architecto quas itaque deserunt aliquam quo molestias dolor ex!</span>
  </button>

  <button>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</span>
  </button>

  <button>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
  </button>

  <button>
    <span>Lorem.</span>
  </button>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, provident laborum itaque ratione nisi enim delectus dolorem dicta quod, quam vitae odit officiis. Ratione pariatur eos sapiente ut expedita. Incidunt?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, provident laborum itaque ratione nisi enim delectus dolorem dicta quod, quam vitae odit officiis. Ratione pariatur eos sapiente ut expedita. Incidunt?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, provident laborum itaque ratione nisi enim delectus dolorem dicta quod, quam vitae odit officiis. Ratione pariatur eos sapiente ut expedita. Incidunt?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, provident laborum itaque ratione nisi enim delectus dolorem dicta quod, quam vitae odit officiis. Ratione pariatur eos sapiente ut expedita. Incidunt?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, provident laborum itaque ratione nisi enim delectus dolorem dicta quod, quam vitae odit officiis. Ratione pariatur eos sapiente ut expedita. Incidunt?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, provident laborum itaque ratione nisi enim delectus dolorem dicta quod, quam vitae odit officiis. Ratione pariatur eos sapiente ut expedita. Incidunt?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, provident laborum itaque ratione nisi enim delectus dolorem dicta quod, quam vitae odit officiis. Ratione pariatur eos sapiente ut expedita. Incidunt?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, provident laborum itaque ratione nisi enim delectus dolorem dicta quod, quam vitae odit officiis. Ratione pariatur eos sapiente ut expedita. Incidunt?</p>

</section>
```

Comment: Aww great! But isn't content-box the default?

Comment: @TonaldDrump not for button elements